# jquery get component with value having double quotation

Tags: jquery

So the following code causes

```
value = '"hello!"'
$(`button[value="${value}"]`)
```

`Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: button[value=""hello!""]`

I understand this is caused by the value having the double quote. However, the value is set dynamically and we accept value to have double quotes, single quotes...
Is there a way to solve this problem using perhaps other syntax?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the quotes so that they become `\"` instead of `"`

```
value = '"hello!"'
// Escaping double quotes
value = value.replace(/"/g, '"');
// Escaping single quotes
value = value.replace(/'/g, "'");
$(`button[value="${value}"]`)
```